# Eyes turn red when posing character

Tags: animation, materials, rigging, rigify, pose-mode

I created a character, used rigify and now, when posing, the eyes turn red. Their texture kinda moves, however they don't when I just move them in *Object mode*.

The character does an animation, where he sits down (just basic for testing). I will provide the .blend file, knowing that it isn't really cleaned up and that there are some backups in it.

[Google Drive for the blend](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1b9quJdxWH_4AvtZ39ONg0AuPLMo1XG6x/view?usp=sharing)

[image]
Frame 0
[image]
Frame 10
[image]
Frame 30 (moved the light a bit so you can see it better)

Comment: I took a look at the file, but I can't see any red eyes. The eyes don't move because you have to manually parent them to the bones. But you want to correct their position first because they are a little off and that makes the eyeball stick out of the head when your character wanders his gaze.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the red eyes? Please remember that BSE is a question and answer page. Your question can help future readers, but only if they can quickly decide if this question is relevant to their problem. Downloading and reviewing a 150 MB file just to decide this is not an option. Also, all relevant information should be included in the question. Cheers.

Comment: I will do so! The red eyes for me occured from frame 10 on.

Comment: Ah ok, I had not played the animation because the rig animation and the cloth simulation froze my blender

Comment: Have you found anything so far? I really dont know where the mistake could be as I never found someone with the same problem online...

Comment: Probably something is wrong with the Texture Coordinate and the Mapping shader nodes and the Eyes 3D position affects the shader. If you hide anything else and rotate the eye, you will see the cornea appears/dissapears on some points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Procedural eyes + armature = bloody-red mess**
The eyes are built procedurally. The shader makes heavy use of the object coordinates and is a bit prone to changes in the object's origin and scale.

You have parented the eyes to the armature. This applies an *Armature* modifier which deforms the mesh. The eyeballs don't get deformed but moved down when you play the sit-down animation. The origin (orange dot) stays where it is during the animation, just the mesh is moved. This finally messes up the procedural shader of the eyes. The iris disappears and the bloody back of the eye with all the veins begins to cover the entire eyeball.

[image: moved eyeball turned red]

**How to fix Rigify eyes**

In a nutshell: **remove the *Armature* modifier** from the eyeball objects and **parent them to the bones** `MCH-eye.R` and `MCH-eye.L` of the generated *rig* (not the *metarig*).

Make sure the origin of the eyeball is at the center and the bones of the *metarig* are at the center of the eyeballs else the eyes will stick out of the head when they are rotated. You can use the 3D Curser (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> pie menu) to align them.

If the bones are a bit off re-generate the rig to have all relevant bones in the right place. Remember to make a backup copy of the mesh with the weight paint if you did already some weight paint. Then align the bones with the eyeballs, and re-generate the *rig* from the *metarig*.

[image: eyes and bones alignment]

Parent the eyeballs to the bones `MCH-eye.R` and `MCH-eye.L` of the *rig*. The MCH- bones are on layer 31. In *Object* mode, select the first eyeball, then select the *rig* additionally (*eyeball* is selected red, *rig* is selected in orange). Switch to *Pose* mode, select the bone, and parent the eyeball to the bone (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, *Parent to  ... Bone*).

[image: parent eyeball to bone]

Once you have (re-)generated the *rig* and parented the armature to the mesh you need to weight paint the eyelids (or transfer the weights from a backup copy if you already did this step).  See [Why are my model's eyes deforming so badly?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/215623/107598) for details.

Hope this helps ...

[image: I can see you]
<sup>I can see you ;-)</sup>

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot!