# Adding extra eyes and eyelid bones controls within the Metarig?

Tags: rigging, rigify

I have a character who has a Boa that has moveable eyes and eyelids, however, I having a very hard time trying to add extra eye and eyelid bones; which I duplicate the set up from the pitchipoy metarig. If I duplicate them while still attached to the face bone, it makes the rig but there are no controls for the Boa eyes or eyelids like the face does(yes I did rename them).

Now if I unparent them from the face bone and try to either parent it to their side shoulder bones or make a new face bone inside the spine bone like that of the face bone, I get errors.

How should I go about this? I have not found an answer or set up for extra eyes controls to the metarig anywhere. I'll upload my Blendfile here(Note that I use 2.79b and cannot update to Blender later versions).

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "a character who has a Boa ..."? A Boa is a snake? The character in the blend file looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJsOk.jpg and the rig looks like a Rigify rig with extensions for the wings and that "horns". Have you tried to generate the rig? There is a button "Generate Rig" where you see the warning in my screenshot. The generated rig comes with controls for the eyes. Usually, they need some manual weight paint and you need to parent the eyeballs to MCH bones. But I don't know the old Rigify rig. Switching to Legacy makes my Blender crash.

Comment: I mean like a feather boa(but its made of bugs), anyways, on my version of Blender 2.79, the rig does generate just fine with no problems.

Comment: Ah, got it. If the eyes don't move properly you can parent them to the MCH-eye.L and *.R bones as described here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/217525/107598 (if it's relevant for the 2.79 rig)

Comment: Ok. I solved my answer. I just added a pitchipoy tentacle from the Rigify Buttons list and added it around the Boa's eye frames and then changed the first bones in Pose mode to "simple tentacle" control then offset parent them to their shoulder bones and it was able to generate the rig with the controls for the Boa's eye frames with no errors. Someone can close this question. Thanks.

Comment: Post your comment as an answer to mark it as "solved". After 2 days delay, you can accept your own answer to indicate this is the correct one that helped you.