# Rigify eye problems

Tags: modeling, rigging, rigify

This model is based on the character Phoenix Wright owned by capcom.

[image]

In general, the modeling and rigging process went well, but there were a few issues I'm not sure how to fix. The base of the red tie doesn't move the way it's supposed to. You can see it in the picture above. I tried playing with the vertex groups to see if I could fix this somehow, but I just can't get this to work. I'm sure I could eventually get it working through brute force. The main problem is the blink.

[image]

Yeah....

The master eye bone that the eyelid bones are supposed to rotate around is in the middle of the eye, which usually works. Not sure why it didn't this time. I can't tell whether it's something wrong with the model, or the rig. If I could get help with this, that would be great. That way I could learn how to do it in the future.

Here is the link for the file: https://www.mediafire.com/file/agpen73hi4ea3xv/Phoenix_Wright_Stack_Exchange.blend/file

Comment: My experience is that the eyes always need some manual weight painting. Your mesh looks a bit dense, not sure if you have applied a Subdivision modifier. Weight painting is usually easier when you have a light mesh. Here is an example of the weight painting for the eyes: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/211089/107598

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I’ll take the poly count down using decimate, and try again. Thank you!